# Customize common navigator framework in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am working on eclipse application. I am using Common Navigator Framework. How to remove the options of Customize View from Common Navigator Framework?

If you need any other information regarding my question, do let me know.

Regards,
Priyank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for it. Extend the CommonNavigator class and override function createCommonActionGroup as mentioned below:

```
@Override
protected ActionGroup createCommonActionGroup() {
    return new ActionGroup() {
    };  
}
```